# Return Map with (unique) key and collection of values that match the same

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a simple object:

```
Value { a: int, 
        b: string, 
        c: boolean, ... 
        some other fields/members }
```

The *key identifier* is generated from the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` — `${a}${b}${c}__${someOtherStringValue}`.

I'm receiving a set of `Value` and I would like (ideally) to use the Stream API to output a map with *key identifier* as key, and the corresponding collection of `Value` objects that matches the key as value: `Map<String, Collection<Value>>`.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't quite work yet...

```java
final var values = Set.of(v1, v2, v3, ..., vN);
final Map<String, Collection<Value>> results = values.stream()
  .map(it -> keyIdentifierFrom(it, someOtherStringValue))
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Anyone with streaming super-powers can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work

```java
final var values = Set.of(v1, v2, v3, ..., vN);
final Map<String, List<Value>> results = values.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> keyIdentifierFrom(it, someOtherStringValue)));
```

Comment: Neat! I didn't see that one ;)